# mongodb asp.net session provider: How to set the application name in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, mongodb, web-config

Question:

I have a custom MongoDB session provider.
It's configured in the web.config like this

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="20" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom" customProvider="MongoSessionStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MongoSessionStoreProvider" type="MongoSessionStore.MongoSessionStoreProvider" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"/>
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

But it throws an exception because the application name is "/"
How can I set the application name ?
**I'm not defining any membership provider and I'm not going to define one anytime soon.**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/paralect/MongoSessionStore/blob/master/MongoSessionStore/MongoSessionStoreProvider.cs) it appears that an `applicationName` attribute will do:

```
<add name="MongoSessionStoreProvider" applicationName="myapplicationname"
    type="MongoSessionStore.MongoSessionStoreProvider" 
    writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"/>
```

Comment: Nope, i tried that before, it doesn't. I also replaced the variable applicationName with a property, where set does nothing and get returns "myapplication", but that doesn't work either. Something keeps overwriting the application name.

Comment: @Quandary - is there a mongo configuration file?

Comment: It's much better than that. If you look at it closely, you see it gets the provider config info in variable config in Initialize in file MongoSessionStoreProvider.cs. But it never sets the application name, so it's the virtual path, which is "/", which is what overwrote my settings... I wonder why this ever worked...

Comment: @Quandary: application name there used as collection name in database and provider initialize SessionStore using applicationName from config in line 71 (as well as connection string).

Comment: @Andrew Orsich: Yep, already saw that. Had to correct the code for actually doing that, however.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify not only application name but connection string to mongodb as well. Full configuration should looks like this:

```
 <sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="20" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
                 mode="Custom" customProvider="MongoSessionStoreProvider">
     <providers>
       <add name="MongoSessionStoreProvider"
            connectionString="mongodb://admin(admin):1@localhost:27020/" 
            applicationName="ApplicationName"
            type="MongoSessionStore.MongoSessionStoreProvider" 
            writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Some notes:

1. Application name will be name of collection in mongodb. (database name is `AspSessionStage`)
2. If your mongodb installation without `--auth` you can take out auth info from connection string `admin(admin):1@`.
3. This provider does not clear expired sessions (need to run some background job to do it)
4. You can report any bugs you may find directly to me.

Comment: Correct, I have hardcoded the connectionstring because I had to update an awful lot, and didn't want to have to deal with a possibly wrong connectionstring, too.

Comment: @Quandary: i am not sure what are you trying to say. What exactly not work for you?

Comment: Just the application name. The session-provider stores info in db[strApplicationName], which throws an exception if strApplicationName is = '/'. I had to alter the session-provider sourcecode to actually read the applicationName property. After that, it worked fine.